# Streaming H264 encoded AES Encrypted video over VLC using SDP file

Tags: video-streaming, aes, gstreamer, vlc, sdp

I am trying to Play a H264 encoded AES-128  encrypted video on VLC player which was received by rtp, How to add a Encryption Key in SDP file .

Server :

```
 gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! 'video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1' ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast  !  rtph264pay ! 'application/x-rtp, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)1356955624' ! srtpenc key="012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

I am using SRTp encryption, the key is "012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" ,

```
My SDP file is 
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96 
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

So I am using above file to stream it on VLC player. How to add the encryption key in this file. ?